# How to build a hierarchical associative array out of two other arrays like "group by"

Tags: php, associative-array

I need help with an array problem.

First I have an array like you would receive from a sql query:

```
$aRows=array(
  array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "a" => "4", "b" => "lala"),
  array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "a" => "5", "b" => "lolo"),
  array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "a" => "6", "b" => "lili")
)
```

Then I have another array which defines the hierarchy - lets say

`$aArray=array("one", "two", "three");`

Now I want to build a hierarchical associative array:

```
$newArray = 
  array(
    "one" => array(
      "two" => array(
        "three" => array(
          array("a" => "4", "b" => "lala"),
          array("a" => "5", "b" => "lolo"),
          array("a" => "6", "b" => "lili"),
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Imagine a "grouped by" sql and I want the hierarchical representation.

EDIT: In the sample one,two,three contains the same values, this would not be the case in real life - assume:

```
select one,two,three,a,b from a_table group by one,two,three;
```

Of course SQL will group equals values in one,two,three together and this redundant information is useless. But sql can not display hierarchic data, so the fields are redundant.

EDIT 2: Thanks to Waygood the complete solution is:

```
$aRows=array(
    array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "a" => "4", "b" => "lala"),
    array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 4, "a" => "5", "b" => "lolo"),
    array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 4, "a" => "6", "b" => "lili")
);

$aArray=array("one", "two", "three");

$output=array();
foreach($aRows as $row)
{
    $newKey = "";
    foreach($aArray as $key) // loop through the hierarchy to get the fields names
    {
        eval('$exist = array_key_exists(\'' . $row[$key] . 
        '\', $output' . $newKey . ');');

        if (!$exist)
        {
            $newKey .= "['" . $row[$key] . "']";
            eval('$output' . $newKey . '=array();');
        }
    }

    eval('$output' . $newKey . '[]=$row;');
}

echo(var_export($output, true));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `First I have an array like you would receive from a sql query` I think that's where you should be looking for your answer. If you store your data in such a way that requires tons of code before you can actually use it something is wrong: either your objects/app design or the way you structured your data

Comment: Since every row of the query would contain 'one','two','three' you would just be removing those fields from the result and placing them in an array built from the hierarchy. Doesn't look very useful, UNLESS you use the values not the field names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to use the VALUES of the fields specified in the hierarchy you can:

```
$output=array();
foreach($aRows as $row)
{
    reset($aArray);
    $eval='$output';
    foreach($aArray as $key) // loop through the hierarchy to get the fields names
    {
        if(is_numeric($row[$key]))
        {
           $eval.='['.$row[$key].']';  // build the key based on the number $row value of each field named
        }
        else
        {
           $eval.='[\''.$row[$key].'\']';  // build the key based on the string $row value
        }
        unset($row[$key]); // remove the field from the $row
    }
    $eval.='=$row;';
    eval($eval);  // evaluate the built up index and set it to the remaining data
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works pretty good, I did not think about eval since its "evil". I will add the complete solution as edit in my question.